# Autocorrelation function for different shifts with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Hi there I'm trying to get a list of autocorrelations for different shifts. My code is the following:

```
thetas = np.array([0.24233997, 0.33467202, 0.35020237, ...])

autocorrelation = []
for shift in range(1,21):
    correlation = np.corrcoef(thetas[:-shift], thetas[shift:])[0,1]
    autocorrelation.append(correlation)
```

This gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:3175: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
c = cov(x, y, rowvar)
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:3109: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
c *= 1. / np.float64(fact)
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:3109: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
c *= 1. / np.float64(fact)
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:1128: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
avg = a.mean(axis)
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:73: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this code or another way to create a list of autocorrelations for many different shifts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because python has taken a slice at an index beyond the scope of the array, and thus has returned an empty slice, which `np.corrcoef` returns errors on.

i.e.`thetas` has less than 22 elements.

This should fix the error:

```
...
for shift in range(1,thetas.size-1):
...
```